# htaccess 301 for multiple domains and files named with spaces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a client who runs a successful set of websites which he has built with raw html.  He now feels it should be databased.

There are two issues I have and I was wondering if there is a regular expression to accommodate them both.

I want his website to run in the one location but use multiple domains.

Also he has named all his files with spaces.

So for example...

I run the site on 
www.maindomain.com

Somebody enters on 
www.domain1.com/first category.html

and I want a 301 redirect to 
www.domain1.com/categories/first-category

or somebody enters on 
www.domain2.com/second category.html

and I want a 301 redirect to 
www.domain2.com/catergories/second-category

Is this achievable? My client has thousands of these pages so I dont want a huge htaccess file with individual 301 redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, you'll need 2 sets of rewrites. First to change the spaces to dashes (-) that INTERNALLY redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "\ "
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ $1-$2 [L]
```

This will loop until there are no more spaces, so "www.domain1.com/first category.html" gets rewritten internally as "www.domain1.com/first-category.html". Then we remove the ".html" at the end and insert a "/categories/" in the beginning:

```
# We need to make sure it has no spaces
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"\ "
# and check that the request ends with ".html"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule (.*).html /categories/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This then redirects (with 301) the internal "www.domain1.com/first-category.html" request to "www.domain1.com/categories/first-category". Now the question is, does the "/**categories**/" have anything to do with the original url ending with "**category**.html"? If so, then you're going to need some additional rewrites.

Comment: Working like a charm my friend!